# What is the difference between windows.print() api and web browser print feature?

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, printing

I've been trying to print my document using two ways.
- using **windows.print()** method and chrome's **print** feature.

When I print with chrome's print feature, it prints all the data well.

But when I print with javascript using **windows.print()**, some of my ajax data is not printed.

After setting up **setTimeout** before **window.print()** method is called, now my data is printing well.

How can this happen? What is the difference between those two?

Comment: Are you talking about windows.print() or window.print()? And what exactly is this "_Chrome's print feature_", how is it called?

Comment: When are you calling `window.print()`? Because it seems like you're doing it early before the page fully loads. It would obviously be different to pressing the print button because it takes you more time to go and click it than firing `window.print` *immediately*.

Comment: @Teemu Print feature that shows up when you press Ctrl + P

Comment: @vlaz I thought so. So I put print script at the end of my DOM. So roughly my DOM structure is like <html><page>{{included page1}}{{included page2}}{{included page3}} <script that calls print> </html> - But the symptom was same.

Comment: But ... but, that is exactly the same as window.print. CTRL+P is just a short-cut.

Comment: `So I put print script at the end of my DOM` since it works using `setTimeout`, there is obviously some asynchronous actions happening. If that's the case then, again, if you are clicking the print button that's *different* to calling `window.print` immediately after loading the page. With the button, time will pass, might even be less than a second but it would still allow for all the async actions to finish - as they might just have been scheduled for the next event loop, while `window.print` executes before that.

Comment: I think the print button you have have a tooltip, so that when you use the setimeout the tooltip disappeared and the print work well